# Convert x265 to x264 on Android

Tags: video

I have HCL me u1 android Tablet 
with following specs.

- Android 4.0 rooted
- display : 800x480
- 1 gb ram
- 1 GZH single core cortex a8 processor
- 5.5 GB free space
- Usb port

this tab is  used only for watching movies with Mx Player App.
Mx Player can smoothly play x264 (480p AND 720p AND 1080p) on Hw or Hw+ mode,but not on Sw mode.

But for hevc or x265 (480p OR 720p OR 1080p) video it cant play smoothely,The A-V sync is horrible.

I guess processor is too old for x265 format.
So I convert x265 to x264 on pc using Handbrake (time 5 to 6 hours) and then I play x264 video  on Tablet.

I am wondering If I could use my tablet for x265 to x264 conversion (tablet can be pluged to charging all the day or even more than 1 day,so no problem of power supply).

does anybody know any app to convert x265 video to x264 video on android?

Comment: If the SoC is too old for *playback* (decode) of the format then certainly it'll perform even worse at *converting* (decode and re-encode) it. You can't expect it to take a reasonable time to complete on your tablet when it already takes hours on your way more powerful PC.

Comment: this is not answer

Comment: and I assume anyone who downvoted ,either tapped dropdown arrow accidently or have no IDEA what I AM ASKING for!!!

Comment: I didn't put it as an answer either. Also, the -1 (not by me BTW) is for something else - app recommendations are explicitly off-topic on Android.SE.

Comment: If you think people are not grasping the idea, it's up to you to explain it further via edits.

Comment: I can if they ask only one time before judging...

Answer (score 1):

You may do the conversion using the ffmpeg tool:

1. Download [**Termux for Android**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en)
2. Install ffmpeg binary by `apt-get install ffmpeg`
3. The command to convert x265 to x264:

> ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 output.mp4